# Is it strange to say I couldn't get out of my bed?

Tags: sentence-construction

I remembered that when I was sick, I was lying in the bed all day.
All the things I saw were spinning around me, so

> I could not get out of my bed

Is it strange to say this?

Comment: It means that something (physical or mental) was holding you in bed. It's not strange to say it and it's perfectly correct.

Comment: I wonder if *laid up* could be used in this context.

Comment: @userr2684291 Yes, if you say something like "**I was laid up after having sex so I couldn't get out of bed this morning.**"

Comment: @SovereignSun I repeat, **in this context**. I'm capable of reading the first definition from the Urban Dictionary myself, thank you very much. [This](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lay%20up) is what I had in mind.

Comment: @userr2684291 You mean "*to disable or confine with illness or injury*" this definition? I guess it's possible.

Comment: Laid up after sex?  Sounds like you forgot your safe word.

Comment: Not only is "I couldn't get out of my bed " grammatically fine, you will find yourself saying it more and more when you get old and decrepit.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not strange to say:

> I could not get up out of my bed.

But I think most speakers would say this under those circumstances:

> I couldn't get up out of bed.

There is nothing wrong at all with **my** there, but compare "go to bed": we're referring to the universal practice.

> I was so delirious I couldn't get up out of bed.